# Is AntiSamy policy actual

Tags: java, android, html, antisamy

I use the following code to filter out javascript code in user-submitted html files on Android:

```
    Policy antiSamyPolicy;
    try {
        antiSamyPolicy = Policy.getInstance(AntiSamy.class.getResourceAsStream("/antisamy.xml"));
    } catch (PolicyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    AntiSamy antiSamy = new AntiSamy(antiSamyPolicy);
    CleanResults result;
    try {
        result = antiSamy.scan(taintedHtml);
    } catch (PolicyException | ScanException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

It loads bundled policy "antisamy.xml" which is included in AntiSamy (https://github.com/nahsra/antisamy).

All seems to work ok. The only question is how actual is the policy? Is it enough to filter out all javascript code in contemporary html?

Comment: The file is from 25 days ago, so if you trust the author it's pretty actual

Comment: The original author of the code was OWASP (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project) which could be trustworthy, but now the actuality of the project is questionable to me...

Comment: AFAIK, antisamy works pretty well and because of its behavior (everything is blocked unless the config allows it), you are pretty safe.